# ¿Como se combinan dos filtros en la misma view de Django?

Tags: python, django

Hola estoy tratando de que en mi template se filtre de la siguiente manera:

- Por fecha con un calendario
- Los artículos (quantityInventory)donde haya menos de 10

El problema es que no sé como agregar dos filtros a mi view. El filtro que es por fecha funciona bien en una Clase basada en funciones y el filtro de los articulos(quantityInventory) funciona bien si uso ListView. Pero al combinar los dos filtros en mi vista basada en clase, no pasa nada. Es decir que no estoy agregando los dos filtros bien. Tienen alguna idea de como se pueden combinar?

**Resumen**: ambos filtros funcionan bien por separado y en diferentes tipos de vistas(funcion basada en clase y ListView), la cuestión es que no sé como juntar ambos filtros en la misma vista

> view.py

```
def pendingStock(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromdate=request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        searchresult = Inventory.objects.filter(fecha_registro__range=(fromdate, todate))
        queryset = Inventory.objects.filter(quantityInventory__lt=10)
        return render(request,'ReporteGanancias/reports-pending-stock.html',{'inventory':searchresult,'queryset':queryset})

    else:
        displaydata = Inventory.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'ReporteGanancias/reports-pending-stock.html', {'inventory': displaydata,'queryset':queryset})
```

> models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
   
    quantityInventory=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantityInventory}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si el modelo que has puesto esta correctamente ya que no tiene fecha de registro con lo que la query de searchresult tendría que dar error.
Si existe ese campo la query sería así:

```
fromdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('fromdate'), '%d/%m/%Y')
todate = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('todate'), '%d/%m/%Y')
searchresult = Inventory.objects.filter(
    fecha_registro__range=(fromdate, todate),
    quantityInventory__lt=10)
```

El en else también lo tienes mal ya que no tienes la variable queryset.